# Ruby ceil is not working for my data in method, only in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have such code in controller's method for rounding (only higher) and display ceil part of number:

```
    @constr_num.each do |cn|
      non_original_temp_var2 = get_non_tecdoc_analogs(cn.ARL_SEARCH_NUMBER, @article.supplier.SUP_BRAND, false)
      non_original << non_original_temp_var2
    end
    @non_original = non_original.flatten!
    @non_original.each do |n_original|
      n_original.price = my_round2(n_original.price * markup_for_user)
    end
  def my_round2 a
    res = (a / 1.0).ceil * 1
    res
  end
```

But for some reasons i see with every price comma with 0 after it, for example: 5142.0  but it must be 5142

Main strange part is that, if i try to write:

```
n_original.price = 123
```

in view i see 123.0
What happend?

Only when i write in view (when displaying price):
price.ceil
i see normal numbers, without comma

What i di wrong? How to ceil my numbers with rounding (but only high, for example 2.24 is 3 3.51 is 4 and 2.0 is 2)? Becouse now for some reasons i see comma and nul after my number, even if i try to "hardcode" number in controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the `next` or `succ` function of the `Integer` class?  Try something like the following:

```
def my_round2 a
  (a.is_a? Integer) ? a : a.to_i.next
end
```

If `a` is an `Integer` then return `a` otherwise cast it to `Integer` using the `to_i` method and call `next` or `succ` method on it.

Reference: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Integer.html

I guess I missed the second part of your question.  To avoid the decimal places I guess you would have to use the `a.to_i` like Philip Hallstrom has suggested.

Comment: @brabertaser1992, which problem the `next` or the decimal places in the view?

Comment: i steal see .0 in numbers

Comment: @brabertaser1992, How about trying `<%= number_with_precision(a, precision: 0) %>` where `a` is your number? See: ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

Comment: number_with_precision  works, but ceil work too. what is better to use>

Comment: @brabertaser1992, I guess using the `ceil` solves both of your problems.  With `number_with_precision` you will need another call to up the number to next integer.  So I would go ahead with `ceil` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your price field is a Float.  Floats will be printed with a decimal spot by default.  You need to either cast it to an Integer earlier on (say in my_round2 method) or in your view task a .to_i onto the output.